# Is there any difference between "Words I learnt today" and "Words I have learnt today" and "Words I have learned today"?

Tags: american-english, british-english

What is the difference between "Words I learnt today" and "Words I have learnt today" and "Words I have learned today" ?

Is there any difference?
When should I use which?

Comment: Learnt, to me, sounds dialectical - Northern BrE; similar in form to dreamt (dreamed) treat [pr. tret] (treated) etc. I live in the South now & rarely hear people use these forms - my partner finds them amusing when I use them, even though she will use burnt or spoilt without realising the irony. I think you're probably safest to stick with the more modern forms.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

1. Words I learnt today.
2. Words I have learnt today.
3. Words I learned today.

The words learnt and learned are the past tenses and past participles of the verb learn. Learnt is chiefly used in BE.

The sentence #1 is in the past simple; it talks of today that is over. 
On the other hand, the sentence #2 is in the present perfect; it also talks of today but it's not yet over. It's still daytime. Of course, you still have some time to learn more words.

Comment: Thanks for pointing out the grammar - past simple and present perfect. It's time for me to revise grammar.

Answer (score 2):

**learnt** is kind of pedantic and bookish, in my opinion - it's better to use **learned**.

**Words I learned today.** Is a list of all the words you learned.

**Words I have learned today.** Is a list of the words you have learned so far, with the possibility of learning more.